# How to switch into edge select mode

Tags: edges

I'm using blender 2.90 and I want to switch to Edge Select mode I'm not able to find anything can anyone know how to do this.Please share the picture it would be better to understand.

Answer (score 4):

In Edit mode on top left corner there are three buttons next to the mode selector. The middle button changes you to the Edge select mode. You can also press the numbers <kbd>1</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd> and <kbd>3</kbd> on your keyboard (the top row, not the keypad on your right,) to enter Vertex, Edge, and Face select modes.

[image: Change to edge select]

You can toggle to Edit mode from whichever mode you are in by pressing <kbd>TAB</kbd>, or by selecting Edit mode from the mode selector on top left corner. It has options Object mode, Edit mode, Sculpt mode and others.

Comment: Thanks for your help bro!!!  It's really important for me.....